# Invalid Operation Exception when filling DataSet

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

The is a database driven currency converter, where the program has to fetch the exchange rates from the database and display them.

This is what I've done so far.

```vb
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT TOP 1 USD,EUR,GBP FROM dbexchangeRates WHERE Date='" & DateTimePicker1.Text.ToString & "'"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnnOLEDB)
    da.Fill(ds, "rates")

    If ds.Tables("rates").Rows.Count > 0 Then

        txtUSD.Text = ds.Tables("rates").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
        txtGBP.Text = ds.Tables("rates").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
        txtEUR.Text = ds.Tables("rates").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString

    End If


End Sub

End Class
```

I recieve an Invalid operation exception on the

```vb
 a.Fill(ds, "rates") '
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post the full exception, including the stack-trace. Please also post the SQL that is used to create the `dbexchangeRates` table - I want to see the datatype of the `Date` field.

Comment: The exception is "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Comment: I used Microsoft Access to create the database and the data type is set to "Date/Time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT TOP 1 USD,EUR,GBP FROM dbexchangeRates WHERE Date= ?"

    Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString),
          command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection),
          adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)

        connection.Open()

        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dt", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        adapter.Fill(ds, "rates")

        connection.Close()

    End Using

    If ds.Tables("rates").Rows.Count > 0 Then

        txtUSD.Text = ds.Tables("rates").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
        txtGBP.Text = ds.Tables("rates").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
        txtEUR.Text = ds.Tables("rates").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString

    End If

End Sub
```

I haven't checked but I wonder if the method `DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged` is being called before `cnnOLEDB` has been initialised on `MyBase.Load`. This way the connection, command and adapter are all initialised at the same time. By implementing `Using` they will also be disposed.

You probably also want to do some data validation to ensure a valid date is set before calling the database with a query otherwise other exceptions could occur.